# $(n-1)$-alternative tensor on E are decomposable

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

> $E$ is a real vector space with dimension $n$ and $E^*$ is dual space of $E$. Assume $\alpha \in Λ^{n-1}(E)$ Show that there exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{n-1} \in E^*$ such that $$\alpha=\alpha_1\wedge\alpha_2\wedge ...\wedge \alpha_{n-1}$$.

Comment: Why is $\alpha$ in $\bigwedge^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $\alpha_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge\alpha_{n-1}\in E^*$?

Comment: I think a star was missing, fixed it.

Comment: @mba There *is* something amiss in your question: either $\alpha\in\Lambda^{n-1}E^*$ or $\alpha\in\Lambda^{n-1}E$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}$ are acutally in $E$... As it stands, the question isn't correctly phrased.

You are using a different convention from the standard one then, because $\Lambda^1 E\simeq E$ canonically in my book.

Comment: @Olivier Begassat: no $E$ is correct because $Λ^{1}(E)=E^*$ and so wedge of $α_1,…,α_{n−1}$ is in $Λ^{n−1}E$

Comment: If we have inner product or symetric non-degenerate 2-form on $E$ then $E$ is canonically isomorphism with $E^*$. if we did not have inner product then can not say $Λ^1E≃E$

Comment: @mba Just be aware that your convention is unusual, just compare with the last sentence in this paragraph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Basis_and_dimension from the wikipedia article.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: thanks for to aware  me , but my book has this notation

Comment: @mba ok, no problem. In my answer I use the standard convention, if that is confusing, I can add modifications to suit your choice of convention. What book are you using btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over some field, and consider $\alpha\in\Lambda^{n-1}V$ nonzero. If $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then there are scalars $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ such that
$$\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot v_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{v_i}\wedge\dots\wedge v_n$$
Where $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{v_i}\wedge\dots\wedge v_n=v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_{i-1}\wedge v_{i+1}\wedge\dots\wedge v_n$. At least one of the coefficients $\lambda_i$ is nonzero. Hence the linear map
$$\phi:V\to\Lambda^n V,\;v\mapsto v\wedge\alpha$$
is nonzero, since if $\lambda_i\neq 0$, then $\phi(v_i)\neq 0$. Its kernel thus is a hyperplane, and let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}$ be a basis of $\ker(\phi)$. If $\alpha_n\in V\setminus\ker(\phi)$, then $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n)$ is a basis of $V$, and there are coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such that
$$\alpha=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i\cdot \alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge \widehat{\alpha_{i}}\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha_{n-1}\wedge \alpha_n\right)+c_n\cdot\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{n-1}$$
then the fact that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1}\in\ker(\phi)$ implies $c_0=\cdots=c_{n-1}=0$, hence
$$\alpha=\alpha_1'\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{n-1}$$
where $\alpha_1'=c_n\alpha_1$.

Comment: Nice answer... I like your writeup better than my own! (Although I like having the concrete example at the end of mine...)

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

Let me make my life easier by just proving this for $E = \mathbb R^n$; I'm going to use the standard basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ for that, and the dual basis $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$, where $\phi_i(v) = e_i \cdot v$, that's defined by the usual inner product.

I'm also going to show that there are functionals $\alpha_i$ such that 
$$
\alpha = r \alpha_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_{n-1}
$$
i.e., I'm going to end up with a real factor $r$ which needs to be combined with one of the $\alpha_i$ to get the result in the form you asked for.

The dimension of $\Lambda^{n-1} (E)$ is $n$. There's a nice map $F$ from $\Lambda^1(E)$ to $\Lambda^n(E)$ defined by 
$$
\phi \mapsto \alpha \wedge \phi.
$$
The codomain -- alternating $n$-forms on $R^n$ -- is one dimensional, generatoed by the determinant function. For any $\phi$, there's a constant $c(\phi)$ with $F(\phi) = c(\phi) \cdot \det$.

The function $c: \Lambda^{n-1}(E) \to \mathbb R$ is evidently linear. If it's zero, then $\alpha$ is also zero, and I'm gonna leave that case to you. :)

So assuming $c$ is nonzero, it's got a kernel, spanned by an orthonormal basis $v_1, \ldots v_{n-1}$. Let $\alpha_i$ be the dual of $v_i$, i.e., the linear functional such that 
$$
\alpha_i(u) = v_i \cdot u.
$$

Then $\alpha_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_{n-1} (v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}) = 1$. And in fact, $\alpha = r \alpha_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \alpha_{n-1}$ where 
$$
r = \alpha(v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}).
$$

Let me do an example: on $R^3$, look at $\alpha = dxdy + dy dz$. For this, we have
$$
F(dx) = 1 \\
F(dy) = 0 \\
F(dz) = 1.
$$
So my $v$-basis will be $s (-1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)$ (where $s = \sqrt{2}/2$). That means (up to constants) that 
$$
\alpha_1 = (-dx + dz) \\
\alpha_2 = dy
$$
so I'm claiming that 
$$
dx dy + dy dz = r (-dx + dz) \wedge dy
$$
which is correct (for $r = -1$).

Now that I've done the construction, I leave the proof of correctness to you. It really amounts to checking that on a basis for $R^n$ provided by the $v_i$s, together with a final unit vector $w$ orthogonal to all of them, i.e., their "cross product", the product of the $\alpha_i$s and the $n-1$-form $\alpha$ give the same values.